# ASP.NET WebAPI Putting Underscores on Returned Element Names in XML and JSON

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am doing some simple testing of the new ASP.NET Web API, and I am experiencing the following problem when returning a serializable class or collection from my action method.

My class looks like this:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class Test

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Name")>
    Public Property Name() As String = String.Empty

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="ID")>
    Public Property ID() As String = String.Empty

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="ClassID")>
    Public Property ClassID() As String = String.Empty

End Class
```

My test action method to retrieve a single Test looks like this:

```
Public Function GetTest(ByVal id As String) As Test

    Dim newTest As Test = new Test() With {.ID = id, .Name = "My Test", .ClassID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}

    return newTest

End Function
```

When I view the results in the browser or in Fiddler as either XML or JSON, the property names of the returned Test class have had unserscores prepended to them, like so:

```
<Test>
    <_ClassID>88bb191d-414c-45a4-8213-37f96c41a12d</_ClassID>
    <_ID>ed853792-b7eb-4378-830b-1db611e12ec9</_ID>
    <_Name>Another Test</_Name>
</Test>
```

How do I get rid of the unwanted underscores on the element/property names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
Public Class Test
    <DataMember(Name:="Name")>
    Public Property Name() As String = String.Empty

    <DataMember(Name:="ID")>
    Public Property ID() As String = String.Empty

    <DataMember(Name:="ClassID")>
    Public Property ClassID() As String = String.Empty
End Class
```

After further investigation it seems that if you do the same thing in C#, no underscores are added and no need to use DataMember. It just works. So I guess this oughta be some VB.NET thingy thing.

Comment: Darin, thanks for the suggestion, but the change had no effect on the output.  The element names still contain the leading "_".

Comment: Weird, this worked for me. Are you using the Beta or RC? I am using the RC.

Comment: RC.  Downloaded and installed from the ASP.NET website.

Comment: Do you want me to send you my sample project that works just fine?

Comment: Sure, that would be great.  BTW, I assume since you said that adding the DataMember attribute worked for you that you are seeing the underscores as well?  Why would that happen?  Not even the standard .NET serializer does that under normal circumstances.  Why would I want underscores on my element names?

Comment: Here's the link: http://www.speedyshare.com/KYKHw/MvcApplication1.zip As far as the underscores are concerned, yes, I am seeing them if I don't use the DataMember attribute. But what's more weird is that if I do the same thing in C#, it works as expected without any underscores and without the need to use DataMember.

Comment: Thanks, Darin.  I resolved the problem using your DataMember attribute suggestion - turns out I just left off the required DataContract attribute on the class, which is needed in order to make the DataMember attributes work.  Still seems like a problem, and the fact that it works OOTB in C# and not in VB seems like a defect.  Thanks for the help and the sample code.

Comment: Thanks Darin helped me alot, would you mind adding the <DataContract()>-attribute to your answer, so that it would be complete even without reading these comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Remove  `<Serializable()>` before Class, then results will not contain "_".

Comment: This was the correct and simple answer for me.  Thanks

Comment: Incredible, haha! I actually just read from the .NET Framework Guidelines book about how the `<Serializable>` attribute is very often misused, and it turns out it was my problem here too. Thank you for this simple and accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience with the prepended underscores in json and I did not have the class marked with the Serializable attribute. In my case the fix was:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

<JsonObject>
Public Class MyObject
...
```